# Download Revision history files from Google Drive

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am using the following code to get all the revisions on a particular file uploaded in Google Drive. I am able to get the link and download the versions but when any other user access the application he is not able to download the file from the provided link.

To get all Revision of File:

```
   private static List<Revision> retrieveRevisions() {
        try {
            String fileId="0BylJDrKIrQebRkpnNEFmZVF3Q3c";
            Drive service= GoogleDriveUtil.getDrive();
            System.out.println(service+"Drive is Here");
          RevisionList revisions = service.revisions().list(fileId).execute();
          List<Revision> revisionList = revisions.getItems();
          for(Revision revision: revisionList){
            System.out.println("Revision "+revision.getOriginalFilename()+"  "+revision.getId()+"revision.getDownloadUrl()");
          }
          return revisionList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        }
        return null;
      }
```

Suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Is the file public or shared appropriately?

Comment: ... and are you using the downloadUrl straight away? It's ephemeral.

Comment: Yes the users are given edit permission on the file before sharing the download URL